# Characteristic function of a random variable with P({X=k}) = $2^{-k}$

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions, geometric-series

Find the characteristic function of a random variable X such that P({X=k}) = $2^{-k}$, $k =1,2,3,4,5, \ldots$

What I was doing is:
$$
\phi_x(t) = E(e^{itx}) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} 2^{-k} * e^{itk} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^k -1
$$

From that, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: $\sum \left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^2$ should perhaps be $\sum\left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^k$, i.e. a geometric series as in your tag

Comment: I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|e^{it}/2|<1$. [So](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Complex_series) $\varphi_X(t)=e^{it}/(2-e^{it})$. Also $X$ is [$\sim\textrm{Geometric}(1/2)$ over $\mathbb{N}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).